# Error in library(xtable) - cannot be unloaded

Tags: r, shiny

- OS X 10.10.4
- R: 3.2.1 "World-Famous Astronaut"

In iTerm,

- (type) cd /directory/for/shiny_app
- (type) R,
- (type) library(shiny),
- (type) runApp()

"runApp()" runs to an ERROR -> Screenshot.
Normal/expected result: R loads all the required libs, eg ggplot2, rCharts, RPostgreSQL …
and the standard browser is open with the shiny app.

The same setup; same OS, same install setup via brew, …, tested and works perfect on 3 devices (iMac). No difference in "env" or ".libpath()".
But whats the reason for that on one device?

[image: Screenshot]-

Comment: You need to post your ([minimal, self-contained!](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) Shiny app here. Otherwise we cannot tell you what’s causing the problem.

Comment: @KonradRudolf add global.R to the question.

Comment: The focus of my comment was really that you post a **minimal** example that reproduces the problem. It’s unlikely that people will wade through tons of lines of irrelevant code, and install dozens of dependencies, to find the problem. Furthermore, I may be wrong but I don’t believe that the code you’ve posted is even a minimally complete Shiny app, so it’s no wonder that Shiny doesn’t run it.

Comment: In iTerm,

(type) cd /directory/for/shiny_app
(type) R,
(type) library(shiny),
(type) runApp()

and after you hit Enter, the loading of libraries starts, and during this loading process the ERROR happens as mentioned in the Screenshot.
This mean, shiny cant start! It stucks with the loading.